# How to update a part of the string using replace function in tsql?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hi
I have a column of nvarchar(1000) type. I need to get rid of encode characters from that column and replace them with their special characters.
For Example:

```
column value is : 'This text values contains this '&amp;' this'.
```

I have to replace `'&amp;'` with '&'.

1. First have to find the record which has `'&amp;'` in the column (may be using like condition)
2. And then replace only this word with its special character

How do i do that? Pl. help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will replace in the entire column

```
REPLACE(MyColumn, '&amp;', '&')
```

You'll have to nest other replacements...

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(MyColumn, '&amp;', '&'), '&gt;', '>')
```

All together

```
UPDATE myTable
SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn, '&amp;', '&')
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%&amp;%'
```

Comment: @Jango: sorry, was rushing and only saw the string replace issue

Comment: @gb: Thanks but i think it won't work w/o mentioning column name after SET or will it?

Comment: @Jango: sorry again. I'm typing on a phone. Not very well either

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET mycol = REPLACE(mycol, N'&amp;', N'&')
    WHERE mycol LIKE '%&amp;%'
```

*EDIT*
If you decide to replace multiple html entities in one go, the order of the replacements may change results.

For example:

```
&amp;lt;
```

becomes `&<` if you replace first `&amp;` with `&` and then `&lt;` with `<`, but the result will be `&lt;` if you first try to replace `&lt;` with `<` and then `&amp;` with `&`.

If I have to do that kind of replacement, I usually replace `&amp;` last for this reason. Sure, an edge case, and not something which happens often, but you never know...

Comment: Actually, i am doing multiple replacements. You have a point. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Generic syntax:

```
UPDATE Table_Name 
SET Column_Name = REPLACE(Column_Name, 'Text_To_Be_Replaced', 'New_Text')
WHERE Column_Name LIKE '%Text_To_Be_Replaced%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update TABLE
Set    field = replace(field, '&amp;', '&');
```