# Update part of String in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I need to update part of the string in SQL Server.

I have:

```
ID   IDCityVisited   Names                    
1    10              Julya,Matheus,Donovan    
2    15              Mary,Donovan,Richard
3    20              John,Bob,Andy
```

I need to update the `Names` column changing only `Donovan` for `Paul` and keeping all the remaining string as it is.

Thanks

Comment: This has [already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856089/how-to-update-a-part-of-the-string-using-replace-function-in-tsql) and should be fairly easy to answer yourself with reference to Google and MSDN. What have you tried and what precisely is your difficulty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Pondlife point me, this worked:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Names= REPLACE(Names, 'Donovan', 'Paul')
WHERE Names LIKE '%Donovan%'
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your table

```
UPDATE tblName
SET Names = REPLACE(Names,'Donovan','Paul')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take SQL server Beginning lesson very serious.

This is what you want to do. a simple replace function will work on your question.

This query will filter the record for Id = 2 then replace function will replace Donovan with Paul.

```
Update TableName
set Names = replace(Names,'Donovan','Paul')
where Id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but SQL Server isn't my focal point. This is why I came here to ask. And the where Id = 2 you anwsered doesn't fill my request. As Pondlife point me, this should be:
UPDATE myTable
SET Names= REPLACE(Names, 'Donovan', 'Paul')
WHERE Names LIKE '%Donovan%'
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET names = REPLACE(names,'Donovan','Paul')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
Tbl
SET Names = REPLACE(Names, 'Donovan','Paul')
WHERE PATINDEX('% Donovan %', Names) != 0
```

**[REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)**

**[PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)**

or this, if you have full-text index on `Names`

```
UPDATE
Tbl
SET Names = REPLACE(Names, 'Donovan','Paul')
WHERE CONTAINS(Names, 'Donovan')
```

**[CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)**

Comment: @Why Contains, He hasn't specified Full text search here.